# $'\n' in double quotes does not work

Tags: bash, quoting

I want to send a string that contains the newline character as a command line argument to my program, the following works:

```
myprogram Hello$'\n'World
```

But when I use double quotes on the string:

```
myprogram "Hello$'\n'World Hello Again"
```

Then the string received by `myprogram` will contain the string `$'\n'` and not the newline character.

Comment: Once you use quotes you can just enter a literal newline.

Answer (score 4):

The `$'…'` construct doesn't work if quoted. Use:

```
$ myprogram "Hello"$'\n'"World Hello Again"
```

or

```
$ myprogram Hello$'\n'World\ Hello\ Again
```

or

```
$ a=$'\n'
$ myprogram "Hello${a}World Hello Again"
```

or

```
$ myprogram "$(echo -e 'Hello\nWorld Hello Again')"
```

or

```
$ myprogram "Hello
World Hello Again"
```

Comment: Bash's manual also lists `$'...'` as a form of [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting), even though the dollar sign makes it look a bit like many other expansions.

Comment: @ilkkachu Last line of [the page you link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting) to `There are three quoting mechanisms: the escape character, single quotes, and double quotes.` So, ANSI-C quoting is not a quoting mechanism, it is something else.

Comment: @ilkkachu is right: `extquote - 
                      If  set, $'string' and $"string" ***quoting*** is performed
                      within ... [blah blah blah]`  The bash man page is very inconsistent; it is a usage manual NOT a computer science treatise.  If you doubt me, have a look through [some of Tim's questions about it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A674+%5Bbash%5D+manual).

Comment: Yes, that's a somewhat confusing sentence since the page lists five types of well, things. Though amusingly, exactly three of them are _named_ quotes or quoting, just not the same ones. Time to start writing bug reports and patches for the documentation?

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, the result of `$'…'` expansion is considered quoted but it is not a way to convert to quoted characters that are unquoted.

Answer (score 1):

The string doesn't need to be contained in one all-encompassing pair of quotes; individually quoted strings can be concatenated into one word.

```
myprogram Hello$'\n'"World Hello Again"
```

Quotes don't define a string; they simply escape every character that occurs between them.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately,

```
myprogram "$(printf '%s\n' "Hello" "world once" "World Hello Again")"
```

The printf command will re-use the format string to consume all the arguments given. Also, the `$()` syntax will automatically remove any trailing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that in three answers, no one has pointed out the simplest solution:

```
myprogram $'Hello\nWorld Hello Again'
```

Since dollar quoting is (arguably) [a form of quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414349/n-in-double-quotes-does-not-work#comment743732_414353), just use that for the whole argument.

Of course, it is certainly worthwhile to understand that quotes are NOT delimiters of any sort in bash.  *White space* is used for word splitting—quotes do not delimit the point where one argument ends and another begins.  This means you can freely mix quoting methods in a single argument.  (There is a good description of this elsewhere on this site already; I will see if I can find it and link to it.)